# Copy name / values from Map to object properties

Tags: groovy

I have an `Object` and a `Map`.  I want to copy all the name / values in the Map to be property values in the `Object`.

So, considering:

```
def tony
def map =  [plenty: "66", none: "0", ...]
```

I want tony to have properties, plenty and none and for them to have corresponding values in the `map`?

Any idea how to do this in a groovy way?

Comment: `tony = map`?  I don't understand the question...  Why not just use the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
class Foo { }

​def tony = new Foo()

def map =  [plenty: "66", none: "0"]

map.each{ k, v -> tony.metaClass.setProperty k, v }

tony.properties.each { println "$it.key -> $it.value" }
```

**Output:**

```
none -> 0
class -> class Foo
plenty -> 66
```

Answer (score 3):

If `tony` does not need to be from a specific class object, you can use [`Expando`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/groovy-goodness-expando-as-dynamic-bean.html):

```
m = [a:1, b:2, c:"foobar"]
e = new Expando(m)
assert e.c == "foobar"
```